# My 2000 Lincoln Navigator does not start, just a click

Tags: electrical, battery, starting, lincoln, navigator

My truck won't start, it just makes a clicking sound. The battery is charged, the starter and solenoid have been replaced and checked all relays, still nothing. I don't know what to do at this point.

Can someone suggest some troubleshooting steps?

Comment: Is it just a single click, or multiple clicks when you turn the key? Do the lights come on inside the vehicle? Outside the vehicle? Do they stay on when you turn the key (ouside: ie - headlights)?

Comment: Check condition of battery cables. Poor connection and corrosion can cause all kinds of issues.

Comment: Interestingly enough the wiring diagram shows two starter relays the solenoid on the starter and a secondary high power control starter relay.   Have you replaced the high power control starter relay?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the battery is actually good--sometimes they can give readings that seem like they're fine, but just not much in the way of CCA there. Best way to troubleshoot for this step: replace the battery, or borrow working battery (friend or mechanic). Second best: hook some cables up to a friend's working battery while running.

Start at the starter. No voltage is getting there. Work backwards. Follow an electrical diagram.